# SonarQube: run analysis on maven module

Tags: eclipse, maven, sonarqube

I've been messing around with SonarQube and the Eclipse plugin, and got stuck on this.

I have a structure of a parent project with children modules, and although I can run an analysis on the parent project, the same is not true for the children. The error message is the following:

> You're not authorized to access to project 'xxxxx', please contact
>   your SonarQube administrator.

It looks like it's pretty straight forward, I just need to add the permissions to work, but the thing is the user I'm logging in from Eclipse is the admin, and it has all permissions set under the security section.

Any ideas on how to work around this?

Comment: Can you precise the version of SQ you are using?

Comment: The latest one, 5.1.2

Comment: Do you confirm you can run a preview analysis on the root module but not on children modules? In command line can you try:
  - run a preview analysis on root module (e.g. mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.login=xxx -Dsonar.password=xxx -Dsonar.host.url=xxx)
  - then try to run the same on a child module